# How are inclusion-wise maximal and minimal sets defined?

Tags: combinatorics, matroids

I have tried to find them over the internet, but am lacking a resource that rigorously defines these two terms.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An inclusion-wise maximal set among a collection of sets is a set that is not a subset of some other set in the collection. An inclusion-wise minimal set among a collection of sets is a set in the collection that is not a superset of any other set in the collection.

Comment: Thank you. That was concise and apt.

Comment: @Aseem You're welcome.